# Calculate cumulative percentage of other columns in SQL (Horse Racing)

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT A.horse, A.datum, Sum(IIf([prev_place] = ---)) AS cum_show_ct, count(prev_place) AS cum_race_ct, (cum_show_ct/cum_race_ct) AS cum_show_pct INTO SHOW_PCT
FROM (SELECT PLACE_2.horse, PLACE_2.a_id, PLACE_2.place, PLACE_2.datum, b.place AS prev_place FROM PLACE_2 INNER JOIN PLACE_2 AS b ON PLACE_2.horse = b.horse WHERE (PLACE_2.datum > b.datum) ORDER BY place_2.horse, place_2.datum)  AS A
GROUP BY A.horse, A.datum;
```

So this expression created the table in the link below. 
http://postimg.org/image/ke08u94i3/

What this did was to calculate a horses winning percentage (in past horse races up to the day of that race). This winning percentage is simply the number of times a horse has showed (finished 1, 2, or 3rd place) divided the cumulative number of races that it has been in in the past up to the day of the race (cum_show/cum_count).  I also have a link below for the PLACE_2 table where most of the data for the calculation is calculated from.

Place_2 Table Part 1:
http://postimg.org/image/68jy808vh/

Place_2 Table Part 2(it has many columns):
http://postimg.org/image/exmvc1c0l/

Place 2 Table Part 3
http://postimg.org/image/cbaf0u7sd/

I would like to modify the above script so that for every time the finish column in table place_2= --- for the horse or that the horse didn't finish the race, the script will pull out a cumulative non-finish percentage  (cum_nonfinish/cum_count_of_races) up to the day of the race rather than the cumulative show percentage. Before it used the place column to calculate the cumulative show percentage.

Thank you so much,

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT original.*, @cumulative:=@cumulative+cum_show_pct 
from (
    your select here
      ) original, (SELECT @cumulative:=0) sess_var
```

That query above suggest a common approach to sum up row values using session variable.

You can wrap the `@cumulative:=@cumulative+cum_show_pct` in any required IF condition.